# How Data recovery and data wiper mechanism works on windows ?

Tags: windows, data-recovery, wipe

I am a competent windows OS computer user . I know `Delete , Shift + Delete` and some of the Data recovery and data wiper tools.

But i don't know how these stuffs are working behind the scenes.

In my first level research i have gone through this [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_recovery) article.

I couldn't get/understand much from this. Could anybody please explain these mechanism ?

I think this should be on topic here . :)

Comment: There are no data wiper mechanics in Windows.  You must use third-party software if you wish to securely delete data within Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound [Yes there is](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/814599)

Answer (score 0):

Your deleted or lost files, folder, or other kind of data does not go anywhere when you give command for deletion. Instead, the index associated with it gets removed when you delete it. The index is the entry of each file of your computer in the ‘Index Table’ of the Operating System (OS). Since a deleted file does not have the index entry in the ‘Index Table’, the OS is unable to find it, despite the fact that file is there at its previous location and physically intact. Moreover, the OS marks the space occupied by this file as ready to be reused. Therefore, in such situation, if you keep on using your hard drive for saving new data, then there are high chances of writing of new data over the deleted one, which eventually causes data overwriting. The overwritten data is impossible to be retrieved even by the most prominent data recovery software. these softwawre work on the mechanism using which hard drive stores data. These tools have used the hard drive data storage process as a ladder to reach to lost file and undo the loss.

Hard disk data erase aims associated hard disk data erasure technology and hard disk data erase tool to completely delete the data on the hard disk can not be restored.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_erasure